# Folder Icon Associations In Mac OS X (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, icons, directory

I know there have been questions asked about creating custom folders and creating Finder sidebar icons which require mach_inject, but my question is a little simpler than that, and I can't seem to find a straight answer, hopefully someone can explain:

When installing Mavericks cleanly (and I think this is how it's been for years), 8 folders are placed by default in your user's home folder (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Library [hidden], Movies, Music, Pictures, & Public).  How are those special folders getting their icons associated to them?  I know the icons are located here: /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/.  Where is finder looking when it 'sees' these folders to know that it needs to dig through that Resources folder and display a .icns file for those folders?

If you 'Get Info' on your Pictures folder from a clean install, the size says "Zero bytes (0 bytes on disk) for 1 item."

If you create a New Folder, it gets the default, generic folder icon (also located in that System Resources folder above, and if you Get Info, it says the same thing: "Zero bytes (0 bytes on disk) for 1 item."  However, if you set a custom icon to your newly created folder through Get Info as [Apple suggests](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10847), the size on disk changes.  It's like your image is being 'embedded' or 'placed into' the folder or something (doing an ls command in Terminal on that folder with a custom icon now shows 'Icon?')  I'm curious to know, how are those icons for the 8 special folders created by default, and the generic folder icons being associated to folders?

From what I understand, Finder looks at a folder, checks a flag to see if it's 'special,' and if it is a 'special' folder, it continues reading some file and says 'ok, this special folder, which icon should I be displaying for it,' and this file tells it specifically which .icns file to go fetch.  I may be understanding this completely wrong, but it just seems like the way Finder associates icons to folders by default is done one way, and then if you set a custom icon, it's associated in a different way and somehow 'embedded' into the folder or something, and showing up as taking up space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System icons association is defined in the file:
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist

If you search this path in google you will find many interesting links about this file structure and how to work with it. It liked the following links:

- https://superuser.com/questions/371892/osx-assign-extension-to-content-kind
- https://superuser.com/questions/364683/add-custom-network-device-icons-in-mac-os-x-finder

Comment: So, I was able to modify Info.plist and actually add some rows.  1 for 'Custom Folder Icon' and 1 for 'Sidebar Custom Folder Icon' and have written in the appropriate .icns files that should be associated to my 'custom folder.'  This seems too easy and I'm most likely doing something wrong.  The last thing I've done is modified the strings in my newly added rows. Item 16 and Item 112 in the two screenshots listed here: http://i.imgur.com/0f4fKW3.png & http://i.imgur.com/QJyisAH.png Any idea how I would go about creating a new folder, then indicate they should use those added strings?